# Basic sql query in microsoft access error

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

```
SELECT 
FROM Query1, Table2, Table3
UPDATE Table2
SET companycount=(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table3
WHERE Table2.CASE#=Table3.CASE2#)
;
```

Here is the query I am trying to run however I keep getting error messages in Access stating that sometthing in the SELECT is misspelled or wrong. Would anyone know why this is happening? If this is too vague please let me know and I will give more info. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: CASE,CASE2, AND companycount are all column names
EDIT2:

Ok sorry about being vaugue the data is confidential so I cannot give much but. Basically I have 2 tables with multiple columns which I have done an inner join with in query 1. Now I was instructed to add a column to the first table:'Table2' to find all multiple values(what I mean by this is there is a column for item number, another for country/state, and another for check amount. Now there can be multiple of the same item in different states and countries.) But the person who mannually put in the data didnt divide the $ amount in the 'check amount' column by the number of the same item. So for example say i have 1 item, distributed to 3 countrys which take up 3 rows on the data table. Instead of dividing the total cost which is $13,000 by 3, the data states $13,000 for each of the 3 rows in the 'check amount' column. So what I want to achieve is, I want to update only the items that are distributed to multiple companies and change their 'check amount' to reflect the amount of countries they are distributed in.(so item 1=$13,000 in 3 countries. end result should be that each country's 'check amount' should be $4,333 instead of $13,000) Please let me know if any of this makes sense and thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: There are multiple syntax errors in this query. To be honest, I'm not even sure of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: are you trying to UPDATE a table? or select some values?  this looks like a bad cut and paste.

Comment: Case is reserved word so use [case], also case# is invalid character in name.

Comment: are you selecting from a query in your first select statement? i think the best bet is to explain your tables and let us know what your trying to do so we can help further

Comment: added an update hope this helps more

Comment: Never, EVER, use a pound sign ("#") in a field name.  EVER.

Comment: thanks @JohnnyBones, didn't know that. I realized I need to do more research and come back with a better question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to do something like this

```
  UPDATE T2
  SET T2.companycount= a.numb
  FROM Table2 T2, (SELECT [CASE2], count(1) as numb FROM Table3 group by [CASE2]) a
  WHERE T2.[CASE]=a.[CASE2]
```

Sorry, the above would have worked on SQL server, try the following for access

```
UPDATE Table2 as T2
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT [CASE2], Count(1) AS numb FROM Table3 group by [CASE2]) AS a
ON a.[CASE2]=T2.[CASE]
SET T2.companycount=a.numb
```

Comment: Hedinn: I ran that and got this message: syntax error(missing operator) in query expression ' a numb FROM Table2 T2